# Не всегда погружает видео с YouTube Api

Tags: javascript, api, frontend, youtube-api

```
let tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
videoId: 'GBj9bxHuuXE',
    events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}

let done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
    done = true;
}
}

function stopVideo() {
player.stopVideo();
}
```

Это JS код, чтобы проигрывалось видео.
После запуска страницы, иногда код срабатывает, иногда нет. Ошибок в консоли нет.
Сайт висит на GitPages.